# Why won't my mysql grant privilege to user?

Tags: mysql

Oddly enough it seems my mysql will not allow creating a user with access to a specific database. Using MySQL Workbench:

```
CREATE USER 'testUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'thepasswordhere';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testDatabaseName TO 'testUser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
SHOW GRANTS;
```

I see nothing mentioning granted privileges for the created user. This explains why I get `mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'testUser'`

What step am I missing?? Update: Even when I mistype the username I still get a success with 0 rows affected: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testDatabaseName TO 'testkUser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;` so I think something's seriously wrong with my local mysql. Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: You may need to do testDatabaseName.*, per the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html, not just testDatabaseName.

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'testUser'@'localhost';`... otherwise, `SHOW GRANTS;` shows *your* privileges -- the ones associated with the account that is currently logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE USER 'testUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'thepasswordhere';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testDatabaseName.* TO 'testUser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
SELECT sql_grants FROM common_schema.sql_show_grants;
```

What changed? I simply added a `.*` after database name. It's necessary so the user has access to all tables inside the database.

Also for the latest mysql, I believe you need to put user password when using grant.

So do as follows:

```
CREATE USER 'testUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'thepasswordhere';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testDatabaseName.* TO testUser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SELECT sql_grants FROM common_schema.sql_show_grants;
```

As mentioned by Michael in the question comments:

> `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'testUser'@'localhost';`... otherwise, `SHOW GRANTS;`
>   shows your privileges -- the ones associated with the account that is
>   currently logged in.

Comment: Thanks but that still shows no mention of my test User with SHOW GRANTS.

Comment: Tried that and it sill has 2 rows in SHOW GRANTS, both are for root, not the testuser.

Comment: Yes, it's root, each of those will run successfully but I see nothing mentioning testUser.

Comment: @Phitter Thanks, yes I did.

Comment: Nice. Btw `SELECT sql_grants FROM common_schema.sql_show_grants;` seems to be invalid though.